# In "Batman: Arkham City" what is the choir chanting when Batman fights Ra's Al Ghul

Tags: dc, batman, arkham-series

In the video game "Batman: Arkham City" when right before Batman fights Ra's Al Ghul the theme plays, and the choir starts to chant, what are they chanting and what language is it in?

Comment: [“AFFLECK! AFFLECK! AFFLECK! AFFLECK!”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21275/what-did-the-people-in-the-prison-chant-in-the-dark-knight-rises)

Answer (score 1):

Not all chants are systemic or have a lyrical meaning. Thought it's not uncommon for them to sing in latin. 
https://genius.com/albums/Nick-arundel/Arkham-city-original-video-game-score